# Initializing a matrix with a pointer to pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Suppose I have initialised a matrix with the following:

```
double** m = (double**) calloc(count, sizeof(*double));
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        *(m+i) = (double*) calloc(count, sizeof(double));
}
```

Now I want to pass this matrix to a function with the following declaration:

```
double func(void* params)
```

Is the following the correct way to get the matrix from params:

```
double** m = *(double**) params;
```

Then I can just access elements in m normally? E.g.

```
double a = m[1][2];
```

Comment: It is generally considered bad form to edit the question in such a way as to invalidate existing answers.

Comment: I see, sorry I thought that it's not relevant to my question and that it's only a typo. But I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters this code snippet

```
double** m = (double**) calloc(count, sizeof(double));
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        *(m+i) = (double*) calloc(count, sizeof(double*));
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
}
```

is invalid.

I think you mean

```
double** m = (double**) calloc(count, sizeof(double *));
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        *(m+i) = (double*) calloc(count, sizeof(double));
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
}
```

This function declaration

```
double func(void* params);
```

does not make sense. The size of the array (matrix) is not known. You should specify the size.

The function can be declared like

```
double func(void* params, int size );
```

and within the function you can write

```
double **a = params;
```

and use expressions like

```
a[i][j]
```

where i and j belong to the range `[0, count)`

and call the function like

```
func( m, count );
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say how you call the function. But if the call is `func(m)` then the code in the function would be `double** m = params;`

The code you posted is a constaint violation (assign `double *` to `double **`).